# Trying to create image from appended array

Tags: image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a list of images in a directory. I am trying to extract a column from  each image (image size is 403 px by 1288 px by 3 bands) , and sequentially build an array from these columns using numpy append that I want to save as an image. I'm trying to use numpy and pillow to make an image from this appended array.

I have researched Pillor, Numpy documentation

```
# !/usr/bin/python3
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from PIL import Image
import os, time, sys, subprocess


savpath = 
    'C:/data/marsobot/spectral/pushbroom/zwoexperiments/fullsuntheframes/'
```

os.chdir('C:/data/marsobot/spectral/pushbroom/zwoexperiments/fullsuntheframes/')

```
toappendarr = np.empty ([403, 1288, 3])

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown = False):
   for name in files:
       img = Image.open(name)
       arr = array(img)

       value = arr[:, 300, 1]

       toappendarr = np.append(toappendarr, value, axis=1)

print(toappendarr.shape)
imgout = Image.fromarray(arr)
imgout.save("output.jpg")
```

I expected an image but instead I got:

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Comment: Maybe check the names and shapes of the files you are opening...

Comment: Also `append()` doesn't seem to be the correct way to overwrite an empty column in an array that already has the correct final size...

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to glob filenames with `for f in glob.glob("*.png"):` rather than do all that walking subdirectories stuff which you don't need?

Comment: You start with an array that is [403, 1288, 3] filled with gibberish.  `np.append` with axis=1 requires that the other array be (403, n, 3) shape.  `value` after the `arr` indexing must be 1d.  It should be 3d.  Or you should start with a correct 'empty' array, with the right number of dimensions.  And the append axis should be size 0 so you don't get junk.  If you are going to use `append` like this test the steps carefully, one by one, and don't make any assumptions.  Test, test, test.

Comment: Alternatively collect the images in a list (list append is faster and easier to use), and make the array with one call at the end.

Comment: Thank you all for responding. With this code I am trying to extract a specific column of pixels at the 300 pixel mark for each image in a folder. This means I have to go through every image in the folder to extract these pixels. I want then to create an image out of all these extracted pixel columns, hence trying to append them to an empty array.